# Error con Vuejs Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estoy intentando enviar por post unos datos, en localhost si me funciona pero al subirlo al servidor no, ya intente de todo, pero me lanza este error:

```
  var formData = app.toFormData(app.newMenssage);
                axios.post("/chat/save/", formData)
                    .then(function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                            app.newMenssage.message = "";
                            app.successMessage = response.data.message;
                            app.getAllUsers();
                    });
```